# The Odd Chemistry Teacher

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, chemistry

My son's chemistry teacher is quite a nice person, but, I'd say, a little weird . Well, it has never been too much of problem -- never before yesterday, when I went up to him for some serious talk. You know, I am quite concerned about my son's studies and all, so I have this habit of talking to his teachers. So I asked him, how he is doing, and perhaps even gave him a hint that I am quite worried about it. All that he did was to chuckle and hand me a bit of paper that read:

> **Balance the Following Equations:**
>   $$\text{Po+Sc+Y+Re+Rb}+\underline{\qquad}=\text{Cs+In+Db+Fe+Kr+Tl}+\underline{\qquad}\;,$$
>   $$\text{Al+Lu+C}=\text{Cm+Ta}+\underline{\qquad}$$
>   $$\text{Re+Cf}=\text{Fr+He}+\underline{\qquad}$$
>   $$\text{Ba+N}=\text{Sn+Er}+\underline{\qquad}.$$

I don't have the slightest idea  what this might mean. Maybe you people can help me out?

---

Clarification:

> There's not much hint on how to proceed in the prologue; it's just flavor-text.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In each line,

> the elements on the left form an anagram of the elements on the right (in American spelling).

The missing elements are

> Line 1: nickel and cerium
> Line 2: nobelium
> Line 3: iron
> Line 4: argon

and their symbols spell

> "Nice, no fear."

Comment: @Ankoganit, fun puzzle but I don't understand the meaning of the answer in the context of the flavour text.  Why did the teacher give such an overly terse reply?

Comment: @Wossname The title clearly says the teacher is _odd_ ;)

Comment: Well yes, but this level of oddity might suggest that he shouldn't be allowed to handle dangerous chemicals in a school environment. :)

Comment: @Wossname No. He should be allowed to. He is so much into chemistry that he talks in the language of chemistry!